# Elliptic curves over extension fields with Galois group the Monster

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, galois-theory, arithmetic-geometry

I was watching Mazur's 2019 Einstein lecture at the AMS joint sectional meeting, and he proposed the following question following a discussion, which I *paraphrase* here:

> Given an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb Q$, consider all extension fields
>   $\mathbb Q'$ of $\mathbb Q$ for which the Galois group
>   $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb Q' / \mathbb Q) = M$, is the Monster group. Of
>   these extensions $\mathbb Q'$, how many possess the property that
>   $\mathrm{rank}\, E(\mathbb Q') > \mathrm{rank}\, E(\mathbb Q)$?

I'd like to be pointed to any useful papers that attempt to address this question, or have results towards the answer of such a question, and perhaps not necessarily just in the case of the Monster, but also other sporadic simple groups.

Comment: Perhaps before studying the case of the Monster group, you might consider somewhat easier simple groups, for example the cyclic groups of prime order $p$. In that case, there are even speculative conjectures that there are only *finitely* many fields $K/\mathbf{Q}$ where the rank increases if $p \ge 7$, e.g. http://mypage.concordia.ca/mathstat/cdavid/PAPERS/draft.pdf.